# Azure C# WebJob Archiving Set of Block Blobs Writes All Archived Images with 0 Bytes

Tags: c#, azure, azure-webjobs

The scripts functional purpose is to take in an array of blob names in a container. and create a .ZIP file which can downloaded at a later time.

After some research I was able to get the WebJob to trigger and add the images to an archive and upload it back to Blob Storage.  Problem is all the files have zero bytes.  I'm completely new to Streams in C#, but have been operating under the premise I can simply pipe the data as needed only having to write the final archive stream back to blob storage.

Am I incorrect in that assumption?

I suspect my issue is related to some async operation while looping through the images, which never finish before the archive is written and uploaded.

The code is below, any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public static void ArchiveImagesTask(
        [QueueTrigger("download")] AssetImagesArchive assetImages,
        string id,
        string email,
        string container,
        string[] images,
        [Blob("{container}")] CloudBlobContainer sourceContainer,
        [Blob("downloads")] CloudBlobContainer targetContainer)
{

    using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(memoryStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            foreach (var image in images)
            {
                var blobInArchive = archive.CreateEntry(image, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                var blob = sourceContainer.GetBlockBlobReference(image);

                using (var entryStream = blobInArchive.Open())
                using (var fileToCompressStream = new MemoryStream(blob.StreamWriteSizeInBytes))
                {
                    fileToCompressStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
                }
            }
        }

        var zip = targetContainer.GetBlockBlobReference($"{id}.zip");
        memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        zip.UploadFromStream(memoryStream);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the problem is here:

```
using (var entryStream = blobInArchive.Open())
using (var fileToCompressStream = new MemoryStream(blob.StreamWriteSizeInBytes))
 {
      fileToCompressStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
 }
```

your `entryStream` is the stream that you write to, in order to add to the zip file (if I understand your code correctly) - so that's fine.
However, you are creating a new, *empty* `fileToCompressStream` with nothing in it; You are just passing in an integer, which is the size of the stream (I don't understand how that compiles, but that's another matter). So, you are adding an empty stream to your Zip file.

You *should* be able to replace the above three lines with this (not tested);

```
using (var entryStream = blobInArchive.Open())
{
    blob.DownloadToStream(entryStream);
}
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblob.downloadtostream.aspx

*If* that fails with weird exceptions - and it may, because Streams in .Net violates the Liskov substitution principle in a big way - you may need to do this;

```
using (var entryStream = blobInArchive.Open())
using (var fileToCompressStream = new MemoryStream(blob.StreamWriteSizeInBytes))
 {
      blob.DownloadToStream(fileToCompressStream);
      fileToCompressStream.Position = 0; // Not sure this is necessary
      fileToCompressStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
 }
```

...but only do that if you have to; You'll have yet another copy of the whole file in memory if you do it that way.

If you are still having problems after that, you *may* need to manually Flush some of the streams; The `using` statements you are using will call the Dispose method on the streams, which *should* flush them, but it's always possible someone didn't implement that properly.

### A side note

you are very right to include this line:

```
memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
```

It sets the pointer in the stream back to the beginning so that when you upload it, you will actually send the data up. You may want to know that MemoryStream has a slightly simpler way to do it, namely this:

```
memoryStream.Position = 0;
```

It makes no difference to the outcome, I just personally like that syntax better.

Comment: You sir, are simply awesome!  The first iteration worked with up to 20 images so far.  Thank you as well for the additional detailed information!